# cron not running in a docker container with no capabilities

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, cron

I have a docker container, in which I'm running the following cron job:

```sh
SHELL=/bin/bash
BASH_ENV=/container.env
*/1 * * * * find ${CLONE_DIR} -mmin +10 -exec rm -fr {} >> /var/log/cronjob.log 2>&1 \;
```

The cronjob works perfectly in my local environment (i.e using docker-compose to launch the container).

In my production environment I use k8s and remove all capabilities from the container:

```yaml
securityContext:
  capabilities:
    drop:
    - ALL
```

Which results in the job not running at all.

Checklist:

- I verified that `cron` service is running.
- No errors in the `cron` script.
- `crontab -l` lists the job

I've tested the container with and without `capabilities` and can verify that with it it works, and without it doesn't. Therefore, I think this is the problem.

What capability should I add to my container in order for this to work?
Thanks for your help and attention.

Comment: what is your entrypoint/cmd for the docker container that keeps the container running? CRON is a background task, and a container needs a foreground task to be running for the container to be kept alive.

Comment: I have a bash script runing my server and the CMD looks like this:

 CMD service cron start && /wait && /server/start.sh

Answer (score 3):

The missing capability was: `CAP_SETGID`

Answer (score 1):

For me (docker 20.10.22) , it worked by allowing:

- CAP_SETGID
- DAC_OVERRIDE

If you don't have a k8s environment to test, you can test in this way local:

`docker run --cap-drop ALL --cap-add SETGID --cap-add DAC_OVERRIDE image`

Comment: Nice one with the local cap test! I had to add another one: `SETUID` (Docker 20.10.7 on Windows).